# How to change php array output

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following function:

```
public function albums($artist) {
        $artist = $this->db->sanitize($artist);

        $query = "
            SELECT `album`, `cover`
        FROM `albums`
            join `artists`
                on `albums`.`artistsID` = `artists`.`id`
        WHERE `artists`.`artist` = ? 
        ";

        $stmt = $this->db->mysqli->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $artist);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

As you can see this will return an array with the `album` name and the `cove` file path.
The array output looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [album] => Album name
            [cover] => file path
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [album] => Album name
            [cover] => file path
        )
)
```

As you can see it returns an array with `0` and `1` with an array of `album` and `cover`.

What I would like it to be is an array which is easier to use with a while loop.
So I can do something like:

```
while($row = $data) {
    echo $row['album'].' <img src="'.$row['cover'].'">';
}
```

instead of 2 foreach loops like I have to do now. So my question is how can I get an array which is easier to use like you would normaly get when you do something like:

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $row['username'];
} //Just as an example to make the question a bit more understandable 
?>
```

I hope someone could help me out on this one. If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: IS this intentional: `on artists.id = artists.id`?

Comment: No, I didn't noticed it before because it gave me the results I somewhat expected

Comment: _“What I would like it to be is an array which is easier to use with a while loop”_ – you should rather use a `foreach` loop for this … then the whole “problem” solves itself without any further meddling with the array structure.

Comment: @CBroe If you post it as an answer I'll accept it because I now solved it. TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I would like it to be is an array which is easier to use with a while loop

You should rather use a `foreach` loop for this … then the whole “problem” solves itself without any further meddling with the array structure.

Answer (score 0):

You're using fetch_assoc() so...

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo $row['album'] . ' <img src="' . $row['cover'] . '">';
}
```

Comment: Since I use it in a class function I return the array. In another file I say `$data = $music->albums('Band');` So how would you do it...

Comment: Just return the $result array then.